# parse JSON file to CSV with key values null in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, key

```
Example

{"data":"value1","version":"value2","version1":"value3"}
{"data":"value1","version1":"value3"}
{"data":"value1","version1":"value3","hi":{"a":"true,"b":"false"}}
```

I have a JSON file and need to convert it to csv, however the rows are not having same columns, and some rows have nested attributes,how to convert them in python script.

I tried JSON to csv using Python code, but it gives me an error

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Since you have nested `dict`/`object` values you also need some logic to flatten them.

Comment: try using pandas library, in a couple of lines you can have a csv from that json. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-convert-json-into-a-pandas-dataframe-100b2ae1e0d8

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a JSON file to a CSV file in Python, you will need to use the Pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
   {
     "data": "value1",
     "version": "value2",
     "version1": "value3"
   },
   {
     "data": "value1",
     "version1": "value3"
   },
   {
     "data": "value1",
     "version1": "value3",
     "hi": {
       "a": "true,",
       "b": "false"
     }
   }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

I have correctly formatted your JSON since it was giving errors.

Comment: this code is not flattening the sub columns "hi": {
       "a": "true,",
       "b": "false"

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the JSON data to a flat list of lists with column names on the first line.  Then process that to make the CSV output.

```
def flatDict(D,p=""):
    if not isinstance(D,dict):
        return {"":D}
    return {p+k+s:v for k,d in D.items() for s,v in flatDict(d,".").items()}
    
def flatData(data):
    lines = [*map(flatDict,data)]
    names = dict.fromkeys(k for d in lines for k in d)
    return [[*names]] + [ [*map(line.get,names)] for line in lines ]
```

The `flatDict` function converts a nested dictionary structure to a single level dictionary with nested keys combined and brought up to the top level. This is done recursively so that it works for any depth of nesting

The `flatData` function processes each line, to make a list of flattened dictionaries (`lines`). The union of all keys in that list forms the list of columns names (using a dictionary constructor to get them in order of appearance).  The list of names and lines is returned by converting each dictionary to a list mapping key names to line data where present (using the .get() method of dictionaries).

output:

```
E = [{"data":"value1","version":"value2","version1":"value3"},
{"data":"value1","version1":"value3"},
{"data":"value1","version1":"value3","hi":{"a":"true","b":"false"}} ]

for line in flatData(E):
    print(line)

['data',   'version', 'version1', 'hi.a', 'hi.b']    # col names
['value1', 'value2',  'value3',    None,   None]     # data ...
['value1',  None,     'value3',    None,   None]
['value1',  None,     'value3',   'true', 'false']
```

Comment: I am getting an error at *map

Comment: What error are you getting?  I just copied and pasted the code and example from this page and it works just fine.  (I'm using Python 3.7)

Comment: I am getting error at *map, I have below code:from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

with open('test_json') as json_file:
 for data in json_file:
  json=json_normalize(json_file)
json.to_csv('data.csv',index=false). How do I add the def flatdata to this code

Comment: I believe the problem is the `for data in json_file:` loop.  It seems to be reading the file multiple times instead of processing the loaded json as a whole.  Also, the `flatData` function expects the json content to be an array at the top level.  if the top level is an object instead, you would need to call `flatData` with the json content inside square brackets.  I'm just guessing here though, you should post the whole code and the actual content of the json file in your question if you need more help.

Comment: the data in the file is this format:
{"data":"value1","version":"value2","version1":"value3"}
{"data":"value1","version1":"value3"}
{"data":"value1","version1":"value3","hi":{"a":"true,"b":"false"}}

need to convert this to csv
@Alain T

Comment: That would not be a valid JSON content.  Delimiters and punctuation matters and makes a difference in how the data will be converted to a dictionary (or list).